# IIS 10 Multiple requests on Windows 10 Home not working

Tags: ajax, multithreading, windows-10, iis-10

After several searches and tries I can't make IIS 10 accepts more than 3 requests concurrently on Windows 10 Home Edition.

I already tried configuring maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU on Regedit, changed ASP Limits Configuration on IIS but no success.

Is this a limitation for Windows 10 Home edition or is it a configuration I can't find?

Edit: IIS Express running from Visual Studio doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: According to this [article](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit), in IIS9  Concurrent Requests Limit is 3. I guess in win10 this limit is still 3. Only windows server doesn't have this limit.

Comment: This article tell about IIS 8 and below but we can assume that this doesn't changed for above versions.

Comment: Yes, I guess the win10 home version also have this limit, I suggest you could try to use windows server.